# Preferred stock volatility model

Tags: volatility, time-series, garch

If I want to forecast stock volatility, what would be the best GARCH model and why? (ARCH, GARCH-M, IGARCH, EGARCH, TARCH etc)

Comment: For stock indexes my favorite is GJR-GARCH because it captures the "leverage effect" (volatility up if stocks down). https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/229786/garch-vs-gjr-garch